# Encontrar un número natural N más pequeño de forma que la suma de los N primeros números exceda una cantidad introducida por el teclado java

Tags: pseint

Hola amigos apenas tengo esto del codigo pero aun asi no se si esta bien, no tengo ni idea de como empezar

inicio

inicio

```
i,x,suma: entero

lea x

i← 1

suma←0
```

mq(suma< X) haga

```
suma ← suma + i

i ← i+1
```

fmq

```
escriba "el numero cuya suma desde 1 hasta que el exceda "x" es, i
```

fin

Comment: Pon un ejemplo...

Comment: No se que mas podria hacer en ese caso

Comment: Socio pon un ejemplo de un caso real para que uno pueda entenderte, explícame con un ejemplo con números reales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deseas saber es el valor más pequeño de `n` que cumpla la siguiente desigualdad.

`1 + 2 + ... + n > k` para un determinado `K`

Esa sumatoria se puede expresar o calcular como:

`1 + 2 + ... + n = n * (n+1) / 2`

Por lo que tenemos,

`n * (n+1) / 2 > k`

`n * (n+1) > 2 k`

El problema se reduce a encontrar el `n` más pequeño que satisface esta desigualdad.

Para ello, puedes aplicar fuerza bruta, el pseudocodigo seria algo asi:

```
n <- 0

Mientras n * (n+1) <= 2 * k Hacer
    n <- n + 1
Fin Mientras

Escribir n
```

Hay una mejor forma de hacerlo en términos de eficiencia, y es aplicar una búsqueda binaria sobre el rango `[0, INF]`, que permita encontrar el primer valor `n` del rango tal que se cumpla la desigualdad. Esto funciona por el hecho de que si hacemos una función `f(x)` que retorne `true` si la desigualdad es cierta, o `false` de lo contrario, entonces los resultados en un "arreglo" (donde la primera posición corresponde a n = 0, luego la siguiente n = 1, y así sucesivamente) seguirán el siguiente patrón:

`[F, F, F, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, T]`, F para las valuaciones que son falsas y T para las que son verdaderas.

Podemos observar que el "arreglo" (la función) es apropiada para aplicar búsqueda binaria, en la medida que queremos encontrar el índice del primer T, dado que se encuentra ordenado.

```
l <- 0
r <- INF

Mientras l < r Hacer
    n <- (l + r) / 2
    sum <- n * (n + 1) / 2

    Si suma > k Entonces
        r <- n
    Sino
        l <- n + 1
    FinSi
Fin Mientras

Escribir l
```